# How to get failureFlash to show flash message in Passport.js local strategy?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, flash-message

I'm trying to implement a passport-local strategy using passport.js

I would like it so that when a user tries to sign up with an email that is already taken, it flashes a message 'That email is already taken'.

I've added the line `failureFlash: true` but how do I get access to the flash message so I can actually get it to appear on the screen?

I'm quite new to this all so any help would be awesome.

passport.js:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('serialize:', user.id);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    console.log('deserialize:', user);
    done(null, user);
  });
});

// Local signup strategy
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(
  {
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  (req, email, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ 'local.email': email }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }

      if (user) {
        console.log('user error:', user);
        return done(null, false, req.flash('signUpMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
      } else {
        new User({
          'local.email': email,
          'local.password': password
        })
        .save()
        .then(user => {
          done(null, user)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('error:', err);
          done(err);
        });
      }
    });

  }
));
```

authRoutes.js:

```
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = app => {
  app.post(
    '/api/signup',
    passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
      failureFlash: true
    }),
    (req, res) => {
      console.log('request:', req);
      console.log('flash msg:', req.flash('signUpMessage'));
      res.send(req.user);
    }
  );

  app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
    console.log('current_user:', req.user);
    res.send(req.user);
  });

  app.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```

Github: https://github.com/drhectapus/voting-app

Comment: did you get the answer? If so, could you please write an answer here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do

```
console.log('flash msg:', req.flash('error'));
```

or

```
failureFlash: req.flash('error');
```

Comment: `failueFlash: true` should automatically stuff the request with an appropriate flash message, right? Do we need to write it ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

In the `done` callback, you can pass on the error message like this - `return done(null, false, { message: 'User exists!' })` and make sure you have `failureFlash` set to `true` in your router e.g.

```
router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google',
{
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true,
        session: false,
}),
```

You'll have the error message available in your views as `messages.error`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is like damn late, but here is what works for me

First, you need to require and set up flash:

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
```

Then, use it through express:

```
app.use(flash());
```

Finally, display the message by using ejs as your view engine

```
app.use('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/login', function(req,res) {
res.render('login', {message: req.flash('message')});
});
```

Display in your template:

```
<%= message %>
```

This is not entirely the code (duh!) but it will give you some idea on fixing yours! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your example,

```
return done(null, false, req.flash('signUpMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
```

should be replaced with

```
return done(null, false, {type:'signUpMessage', message: 'That email is already taken'});
```

It’s passport itself that will call `req.flash()` for you.

Assuming that you already have setup `connect-flash` and you **verified that you can already show flashes** other than passport flashes then you have 3 options:

### failureFlash: true

In this case when you call `done(null, false, {type: 'info', message: 'my message'})` passport will take the `type` and `message` and use it to call `req.flash(type, message)`, if you don't specify a `type` then passport will default to the `error` flash.

In the example below, there are two possible messages that can be flashed `username not found!` and `incorrect password`, note that we don't pass a
`type` in the `done(null, false, {...}` so all flashes will "inherit" the `error` flash type:

```js
 passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
        // we need to call done(null, user) if authenticated
        // or done(null, false, {message: "invalid username/password"}) if can't authenticate
        User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { done(err); }
            if (!user) { 
                return done(null, false, {message: "username not found!"});
            }
            user.checkPassword(password, function(err, result) {
                if (err) { return done(err);}
                if (result) { 
                    return done(null, user);
                }
                return (null, false, {message: 'incorrect password'});
            } )
        })
    }));
```

### failureFlash: "some generic message"

This will ignore whatever `{type: xxx, message: yyy}` that you pass in the `done(null, false, {...}` and it's equivalent to use `{type: "error", "message": "some generic message"}` in all `done(null, false, ...)`

### failureFlash: { "type": "info" }

This overwrite the flash type of all messages to `info`. So regardless of what `type` is specified by the call to `done(null, false, {type: "myflashtype", message: "my message"}`  that will be effectively overwritten to
`req.flash('info', 'my message')`

I don't think this is particularly well documented in [passport.js docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) but you can find the details by looking at this section of [passport source code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/076850c29c4221c53baae9bbff00dd293e5809f0/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L115-L127)